# Switch stylesheet in single page app

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, single-page-application

We have a single page app built with angular that contains various features within.

One of these features is a drag and drop interface for snippets of code. Each of these snippets has its own styles that are styled separately from the rest of the admin panel.

The main part of the app is styled using a bootstrap theme but the drag and drop snippets are not and so when navigating into the drag and drop section the snippets inherit some of the bootstrap styles.

This causes a variety of problems styling wise and am looking for a solution ideally without using iframes or having to override bootstrap styles.
Ideally we would unload the bootstrap and then only load in the new styles, or have the new content not inherit styles.

Is there anyway to achieve this without reloading the app or using an iframe? Switching stylesheet or injecting new styles into the page and removing others?

Comment: You can try adding an id to link tag that loads stylesheet, and when loading to the second page remove that link tag, inject custom link tag. This will not reload new style, force a redraw by doing display:none and display:block on body.

Comment: What if there are styles on elements surrounding the newly added content which are reliant on the original stylesheet?

Comment: What you can do is include the new stylesheet on just that page BELOW the bootstrap css. This should override bootstraps css and customize your drag n' drop with your new stylesheet.

Comment: Yes if we wanted to inherit bootstrap styles, or override allthe default ones. Bootstrap has a lot of base styles for UI elements that we have not overridden in the drag and drop section. These are not styles using bootstrap whereas the main app is, thus causing the problem

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two options:

1. **Remove the stylesheet element**
   Before displaying your problematic content, remove the LINK element (worth keeping it as a reference for later.

   ```
   var element = document.querySelector('link[href~="bootstrap.css"]'); 
   document.removeChild(element);
   ```

   When you want to return the Bootstrap styling you can just re-append it.

   ```
   document.head.appendChild(bootstrapLinkElement);
   ```
2. **Override the Bootstrap CSS rules**
   Create a set of rules that override and/or reset the Bootstrap rules. You can nest them under a parent selector (e.g. `.no-bootstrap`) so they will affect only specific elements.
   To make things easier you can get Bootstraps precompiled source code (LESS or SASS) and edit it to incorporate an override stylesheet.

*Edit: fixed typo*

Comment: If I've understood #1 correctly this fiddle shows it doesn't work unfortunately. http://jsfiddle.net/bheCw/2/

Comment: Not sure what you were going in that Fiddle but by clicking either button I get different colour squares.

Comment: Here is a little demo for toggling a stylesheet by removing it's node.
[http://jsbin.com/lilic/2/embed](http://jsbin.com/lilic/2/embed?html,js,output)

Comment: That's not what we're trying to do.. We're trying to put an element on the page with an attached stylesheet and not have the stylesheet from the rest of the pages styles affect said element.

Comment: In that cause I suggest taking the second step and overriding any unwanted specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure if its the exact answer of your question, but you can try with:

`<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="/{{snippet}}.css">`

and then in your controller:

$rootScope.snippet= 'xxx';

Comment: ng-href will prevent any call to {{snippet}}.css unless {{snippet}} is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I an assuming that because you have a single page application you are using angular routing, as such it is possible set it up to have route dependent style sheets you can either role your implementation:

In the header of the page you would include this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="{{css}}">
```

In each route in the .when you would add:

```
.when('/somepage, {
   templeteUrl: 'somepage.html',
   css: 'yourcss.css'
});
```

Or you could look into [angular-route-styles](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-route-styles) or [here](https://github.com/tennisgent/angular-route-styles) that I believe is setup to do much the same, however adds the functionality to $routeProvider and provides a means to add several CSS partials to the route. I feel this is a more angular approach and feels like this functionality should be included in the angular base.